# Products list export issue on Magento 1.9.2.2 ( looks like this relate with DailyDeal extention of webins )

Tags: php, magento

I installed the Dailydeal extension a few days ago, but this extension does not support Magento CE 1.9.2.2, so I have uninstalled the extension.

After I uninstalled, I could not open the categories manager of in Magento admin. The error logs show me errors like the below:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:117:"Model-font "Webinse_DailyDeals_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Days" not found to atribute "deal_update_days"";i:1;s:4101:"#0 /home/porto250/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Modelo-fonte "W...')
```

I deleted all related values from database according to developer guides.

Some days ago when I tried to export Magento products list to a CSV file the error above showed up again:

```
"Source model "Webinse_DailyDeals_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Days" not found for attribute "deal_update_days"";i:1;s:5468:"#0 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "W...')
#1 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(203): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#8 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#11 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#14 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(40): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#19 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#20 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#21 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks()
#22 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#23 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#24 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#25 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#26 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#27 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#29 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#30 /Applications/magento-1.9.2.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#31 {main}";s:3:"url";s:99:"/magento/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/197356e029935facd800286f0a12c174/css/styles.css";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I need to list all products in a CSV file. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the extension you installed has created a few attributes, and by uninstalling the extension the attributes have not been removed correctly.

The error specifically is caused by an entry in the `eav_attribute` table (`deal_update_days`) saying that its source model is `Webinse_DailyDeals_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Days`. When Magento tries to find that class, it fails and throws an exception.

If you can log into the admin panel, navigate to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Categories, and search for "deal_update_days". Delete the attribute and any other ones that look like they were  installed by the extension.

If you need to find out which attributes were installed by the extension, have a look through the setup/upgrade scripts in the code for the extension (`app/code/local|community/Webinse/DailyDeals/sql/....`) - there should be scripts either installing batches of attributes or single ones per file.

In future, best to take a database backup before you install extensions.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help ! i cloud get some hint from your help . 
i could find  " (188, 4, 'deal_update_days_product', NULL, NULL, 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'multiselect', 'Deal Products will be run and update each', NULL, 'Webinse_DailyDeals_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Days', 0, 1, NULL, 0, NULL),
"  in exported sql file.
but   error message shows "deal_update_days" not "deal_update_days_product" as sttribute .. it was not exact matched
so i delete this low from eav_attribute table ..
so works fine !!!!

## webise developer guid is like below ..  there is no "deal_update_days_product" !!!!

In your database, in table `eav_attribute` remove entries with following `attribute_code`:

- deals_choice_category
- choice_type_dealstime
- deal_discount_percent
- deal_qty_product_percent
- deal_category_id
- qty_deal_product
- deal_update_days
- old_special_date_to
- old_special_date_from
- old_special_price
- deal_statuses
- deal_status
- deal_bought
- deal_qty
- deal_end_time
- deal_start_time
- deal_price

In SQL language : DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` in ('deals_choice_category', 'choice_type_dealstime', 'deal_discount_percent', 'deal_qty_product_percent', 'deal_category_id', 'qty_deal_product', 'deal_update_days', 'old_special_date_to', 'old_special_date_from', 'old_special_price', 'deal_statuses', 'deal_status', 'deal_bought', 'deal_qty', 'deal_end_time', 'deal_start_time', 'deal_price');

thanks Robbie Averill